# SWIFT - UITableViewCell updating based on selection

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, tableview

I have a TableViewController (lets call TVC1) with a row that says "OD" (which stands for Outer Diameter).

Upon selecting this row, a bunch of rows in a new TableViewController (lets call TVC2) containing the various OD (casingOD in my code) shows. What I want to happen is when the user selects the OD it will segue back to the main TableViewController with the string that corresponds to the user selection. My code for this currently fails...Could anyone help point me in the right direction? If you require TVC1 code i'll happily post it, i'm just trying to save any unneccessary code reading for you folks :)

My TVC2 code is as follows:

```
import UIKit

class CasingSelectionTableViewController: UITableViewController {

var selectedData: Data?

let casingOD = ["114.3", "127.0", "139.7", "168.3" , "177.8", "193.7", "219.1", "244.5", "247.6", "273.1", "298.4", "298.4", "339.7", "406.4", "473.0", "508"]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    switch selectedData! {

    case .OuterDiameter:
        print(casingOD)

    case .Weight:
        print(casingWeight114) // I deleted the casingWeight114 line of code as its not required for this question

    case .InnerDiameter:
        print(id114) // I deleted the id114 line as its not required for this question
    }
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    return casingOD.count

}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    var casingSpec: UITableViewCell!

    if selectedData == Data.OuterDiameter {
        casingSpec = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("selectedCasingSpec", forIndexPath: indexPath)
        let casingODSpec = casingOD[indexPath.row]
        casingSpec.textLabel?.text = casingODSpec
        return casingSpec
    } else {
        return casingSpec
    }

}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let selection: UITableViewCell!
    selection.textLabel?.text = indexPath.row as! String

}
```

Comment: what i understand from this is: You've a tableViewController. on selecting a row, you navigate to some other controller (Tableview) with some rows. What you want is to navigate back to the 1st table view controller with proper selected data. Is it so? @Matty

Comment: what approach have you used yet? You can use notifications or delegates for this. 
+ Your question is very ambigous, must edit this. There's too much extra info. Need to be on point.

Comment: @FyzaNawaz I have added the didSelectRow method at the bottom of my code , but i am getting errors in that function. Obviously it's not correct so I was hoping somebody can point me in the right direction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What I want to happen is when the user selects the OD it will segue back to the main TableViewController with the string that corresponds to the user selection.

First of all you'll need to implement a way for `TVC2` to notify `TVC1` that a value has been selected.

A common way to do such thing is by using delegation. You can define a delegate protocol like this:

```
protocol TVC2Delegate {
    func tvc2(tvc2: TVC2, didSelectOuterDiameter outerDiameter: String)
}
```

Then add a `var delegate: TVC2Delegate?` property to `TVC2`.

You'll then make `TVC1` comform to `TVC2Delegate` by implementing that method in `TVC1`.

When presenting `TVC2` from `TVC1` remember to set it as the delegate for `TVC2`.

```
// In TVC1
tvc2.delegate = self
```

To connect `TVC1` and `TVC2` you could add a bit o logic to your `tableView(tableView:,didSelectRowAtIndexPath:)` method call the delegate with the selected value

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let stringValue = indexPath.row as! String

    // Do anything you need to do related to TVC2 here.
    // Then finally

    delegate?.tvc2(self, didSelectOuterDiameter: stringValue)
}
```

Finally, in `TVC1`'s implementation of the delegate method you can take care of dismissing `TVC2` if needed.

**Update:**

This is how the final implementation of these bits might look like:

```
// In TVC1
class TVC1: UITableViewController, TVC2Delegate {

    // ...

    // Implement the method(s) of TVC2Delegate
    func tvc2(tvc2: TVC2, didSelectOuterDiameter outerDiameter: String) {
        // Do whatever you need to do with the outerDiameter parameter
    }

}

// In TVC2
protocol TVC2Delegate {
    func tvc2(tvc2: TVC2, didSelectOuterDiameter outerDiameter: String)
}

class CasingSelectionTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    var delegate: TVC2Delegate?

    // ...

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        let stringValue = casingOD[indexPath.row]

        // Do anything you need to do related to TVC2 here.
        // Then finally

        delegate?.tvc2(self, didSelectOuterDiameter: stringValue)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will try this out and let you know the outcome!

Comment: No worries. More on the delegate pattern here https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Delegation.html

Comment: would you be able to clarify for me what you mean when you say "make TVC1 conform to TVC2Delegate by implementing that method in TVC1" ? I have declared the protocol in my TVC2 and added the delegate property...however i'm quite new to coding so i'm not entirely sure how to correctly implement the method in TVC1. What i've done so far is I went back to TVC1 and at the end of my Class declaration, I called TVC2Delegate {...} and within this class I will enter the tvc2.delegate = self

Comment: No worries @Matty. I updated the answer with a sample of how the two view controller might look like.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. I've made the changes you've suggested however the string name does not get passed onto TVC1 when I select the row from TVC2. I've added this piece of code within the didSelectRow method `let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as UITableViewCell` followed by `let stringValue = cell.textLabel?.text` then `delegate?.tvc2(self, didSelectOD: stringValue!)`

Comment: Good to hear that you worked it out @Matty :). Keep in mind something, by using `stringValue!` you are implicitly unwrapping an optional value, which can lead to crashes at runtime. Always use an `if let` or `guard let` construct to be safer. This might be helpful in that regard http://natashatherobot.com/swift-guard-better-than-if/

Comment: I believe I spoke too soon. The code I have with what I mentioned on my previous comment does not work. When I click on the row in TVC2, it doesn't dismiss the TVC2 to bring me back to TVC1 with the selected value...suggestion? Sorry to bother you again but I very much appreciate your time!

Comment: I've dismissed the TVC2 by adding the line of code `self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)` however the issue of having the string value passed back to TVC1 is still present.

Answer (score 1):

Use the delegate approach as suggested in the answer by @Mokagio. And in case you're having issue in getting the string, here is the answer

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! UITableViewCell
let stringValue = cell.textLabel.text  //You can get this from your datasource as well)

//call the delegate

}
```

Comment: When you say call the delegate, do you simply refer to me calling `delegate?.tvc2(self, didSelectOD: stringValue)` ?